# Will Security SE upgrade to the latest SE profile dashboard?

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, design

Stack Overflow recently migrated to [a new profile dashboard](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/). Are Security SE admins planning to upgrade as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page you linked to says this in the top paragraph:

> Anyway, as of today, it’s live on SO and about half the network, and we’ll be rolling out to the rest over the next few weeks.

Comment: Down-voting 'cause it's been a lot longer than a "few weeks" since that post now. And, since then, they've already started working on and rolling out unrelated feature updates & UI changes across the network. Please get us an update.

Comment: No update on this yet (I am in very poor connectivity) but I will try to get more info asap.